# Can I combine manual instantiation with autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, binding, code-injection, autowired

Ok.  I am not sure how to even ask the question, which is the sign I must be missing something.  The best I can do is: "Is there a way to instantiate an object manually and still use injection within that object?"

Concretely, say I have:

```
class A {

   public A(MyObject1 obj1, MyObject2 obj2, ..., MyObjectn objn) {
     ...
   }

}
```

I want to wire all of these objects except MyObjectn.  As far as I know, if I use @Autowired in front of that constructor above, then I should only instantiate that object as follows in the code that uses an instance of that class:

```
@Autowired
A a;
```

which doesn't allow me to pass in objn in the constructor manually.  Is there a way to get around that limitation short of manually initializing A in the code that uses an instance of that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - no.
You either use an IoC or you manually instantiate Objects.

One workaround that comes to my mind:

Create a Service with every MyObject1 being `@Autowired`

create a method inside this service:

```
public A createA(MyObjectN objn) {
   return new A(object1, object2... objn); //note that object1 .. objectn-1 are autowired.
}
```

Inject the service with `@Autowired` ;) and call `service.createA()`

Comment: Now that's an idea... I don't know if that's standard practice, but I could see how this could solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

sunilkumar from vmoksha

**NO** we cant create like that