# @Autowired and instantiation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I found the following code.

```
 public class Foo {
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService = new MyService();
 }
```

Does it mean that Spring would overwrite the instance of myService which is created when Foo is created?

This code makes it possible to use Foo in Junit-context without starting in a springcontext.

Is it okay to do things like that?

Comment: You should use Spring's JUnit integration to execute your tests instead of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122622/can-i-combine-manual-instantiation-with-autowiring

Comment: You should be doing one or the other depending on if you need state

Comment: You should use *constructor injection* instead of doing this. That gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not okay to do things like that. Instead:

```
@Service
public class Foo {

    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public Foo(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService;
    }

}´
```

This way Spring injects your required dependency when constructing the Service. For a JUnit context you just need to provide it yourself, it could be as a real instance or as a mock:

```
@Test
public void testFoo(){
    MyService mockService = mock(MyService.class);
    Foo foo = new Foo(mockService);
    foo.myMethod();
    verify(/*Check that foo has done whatever you want with MyService*/);
}
```

Comment: Just to add silly comment, but sometimes helpful, mock here is from Mockito framework I believe ?

Comment: Yes, but you could use any orher mocking library

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answer, you can also run it using ContextConfig as below if you are using Spring 4

Using SpringBoot, you can create bean using @Bean annotation and then autowire it

```
class MyTestConfig{
@Bean
public MyService myService(){
 return new MyService();
};

}
```

Run test case with MyTestConfig as contextConfiguration and autowire as

```
@Autowired
public MyService myService
```